# Replace second last occurrence of a char(dot) in an email string using regex

Tags: javascript, java, regex, typescript, algorithm

Please i would love to replace the second last occurrence of a char in a, the length of the strings can vary but the delimiter is always same I will give some examples below and what I have tried
Input 1: james.sam.uri.stackoverflow.com

Output 1: james.sam.uri@stackoverflow.com

Input 2: noman.stackoverflow.com

Output 2: noman@stackoverflow.com

Input 3: queen.elizabeth.empire.co.uk

Output 3: queen.elizabeth@empire.co.uk

My solution

```
//This works but I don't want this as its not a regex solution
const e = "noman.stackoverflow.com"
var index = e.lastIndexOf(".", email.lastIndexOf(".")-1)
return ${e.substring(0,index)}@${e.substring(index+1)}

Regex
e.replace(/\.(\.*)/, @$1)
//this works for Input 2 not Input 1, i need regex that would work for both, it only matches the first dot
```

Comment: Why not replace `.@` with `@`

Comment: I dont get what you mean,

Comment: As someone who hates dealing with regex, I would split it to an array with the “.” character, then combine the third last and second last array elements with the @ in the middle, then join the array back to a string.

Comment: `/\.([^.]+\.[^.]+)$/` – you need to match the single dot, followed by a not-dot one or more times, followed by another literal dot, that is again followed by a non-dot one or more times - and anchor it all to the end. The whole thing will fall flat of course for `queen.elizabeth.empire.co.uk` :-)

Comment: Something along these lines: `var res = e.replace(/\.([^.]+\.[^.]+$)/g, "@$1")`

Comment: damn where are all the genius programmers on stack overflow

Answer (score 2):

The issue in the example data for the second last dot, is that the last example ends on `.co.uk`

One option for these specific examples could be using a pattern to exclude that specific part.

```
(\S+)\.(?!co\.uk$)(\S*?\.[^\s.]+)$
```

- `(\S+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ non whitespace chars
- `\.(?!co\.uk$)` Match a `.` followed by a negative lookahead asserting directly to the right is not `co.uk`
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `\S*?\.` Match 0+ times  a non whitspace char non greedy and then a `.`
  - `[^\s.]+` Match  1+ times a non whitespace char except a `.`
- `)` Close group 2
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7B3leP/1).

```js
[
  "james.sam.uri.stackoverflow.com",
  "noman.stackoverflow.com",
  "queen.elizabeth.empire.co.uk"
].forEach(s =>
  console.log(s.replace(/(\S+)\.(?!co\.uk$)(\S*?\.[^\s.]+)$/, "$1@$2"))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach:

```
(\S+)\.(\S+\.\S{3,}?)$
       (            )$  At the end of the string, capture by
             \S{3,}?    lazily matching 3+ non-whitespace characters
        \S+\.           and any non-whitespace characters with period in front.
(\S+)\.                 Also capture anything before the separating period.
```

Notably, it would fail for an email like `test.stackoverflow.co.net`. If that format is a requirement, I'd recommend a different approach.

```js
[
  "james.sam.uri.stackoverflow.com",
  "noman.stackoverflow.com",
  "queen.elizabeth.empire.co.uk",
  "test.stackoverflow.co.net"
].forEach(s =>
  console.log(s.replace(/(\S+)\.(\S+\.\S{3,}?)$/, "$1@$2"))
);
```